# In angular js application how to make other codes wait until some code are done?

Tags: angularjs

In angular js application, if have to send a request to the database, and until response comes no other actions should be done, Now I am not able to do that

```
function checkStep() {
  if (currenctStep == 1 && checkBalance()) { // request database to check balance
    alert('balance is not enough');  
  } else if (currentStep == 2) {
    goToNextStep();
  } else if (currentStep == 3) {
    validateAll();
  }
 // ... some actions should wait until above codes are executed, 
 // here some codes that do some actions and should change current step after 
 // checkBalance() respose comes
}
```

What can I do in order to make all other codes wait until the response comes in `checkBalance()`

Answer (score 0):

`checkBalance` is a async call, ti should return a promise.

Something like:

```
function checkStep() {
  if (currenctStep == 1) { // request database to check balance

   checkBalance().then(function (response) {
       // parse response data
       if (currentStep == 2) {
         goToNextStep();
        } else if (currentStep == 3) {
        validateAll();
      }
   }, function (error) {
       // failed to call DB                        
   });
  } 
 // ... some actions
}
```

where `checkBalance` can be:

```
function checkBalance() {
     // some call DB here
    return $http({method: 'GET', url:URL}).then(function (result) {
       return result;                            
    }, function (error) {
         console.error(error);
          return $q.reject(error);
    });  
  };
```

Comment: What i meant is that , when a call to the Db takes some time, the below code // ... some actions are excetuted without waiting, I need these codes should also wait\

Comment: this is not what you described, you have `if else`, how it should be called if `currenctStep =1`?

Comment: @AbbosBukaboyev do you change currenctStep after the response from `checkBalance `?

Comment: below the code is 'What can I do in order to make all other codes wait until the response comes in checkBalance()'' all other code should wait was written

Comment: yes I change currentStep after respose comes and below codes // ... some actions are done, if some codes validate all the form then i change currentStep